# mysql workbench md5 column - how to?

Tags: md5, mysql-workbench

Does anyone know how/where can we apply to a column, a md5 encryption.

I'm creating a user password table and on the password column I would like to apply md5 encryption.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an 'md5()' function that when given a string will return a string of 32 hex digits. Just create a column of char(32) to hold it should do the trick.

See [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_md5).

In terms of using this within MySql workbench, I don't think it's possible to mark a column to contain an md5 hash explicitly as really you can simply put an md5 hash in a char column as mentioned above. I don't believe that you can have a column implicitly perform the md5 function call on an inserted string in this fashion. (I could be wrong).

Comment: So we don't need to format the column with special features, it will be just a varchar(32) one, with no special requirements is that it?

Comment: As far as I'm aware that's correct, in the event where you insert data to the table you'll pass the string to the md5 function.

Comment: As a side note, when editing data however in mysql workbench, you can pass a function in as an entry and it will be evaluated in most cases see [here](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/programming/mysql/wb-intro.html) at section "16.5.7.4.6. Live Editing Tabsheets".

Comment: Yes I was aware of that but it's a nice comment that should prevail. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Taken from mysql workbench manual:

> It is possible to enter a function, or other expression, into a field.
>   Use the prefix \func to prevent MySQL Workbench from escaping
>   quotation marks. For example, for the expression md5('fred'), MySQL
>   Workbench normally would generate the code md5(\'fred\'). To prevent
>   this, enter the expression as \func md5('fred') to ensure that the
>   quoting is not escaped.

Answer (score 0):

More than a years now...  but if someone else fall here like I did :-)

And it goes like this:

> Note It is possible to enter a function, or other expression, into a
>   field. Use the prefix \func to prevent MySQL Workbench from escaping
>   quotation marks. For example, for the expression md5('fred'), MySQL
>   Workbench normally would generate the code md5(\'fred\'). To prevent
>   this, enter the expression as \func md5('fred') to ensure that the
>   quoting is not escaped.

Whole doc [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-table-editor.html).

Answer (score 0):

The `/func` thing didn't work for me. It was always ignoring it and treated it as a String.
However I was able to trick the Workbench with some SQL-Injection.

Writing a ( SELECT ... )-statment just worked. So I put this in my field:

```
( SELECT GeomFromText( 'POLYGON (( 0 -90, 0 90, 360 90, 360 -90, 0 -90)) ' ) )
```

and it filled the databese field with the  polygon-object and not the string.